# How do you write multiple variables to a text file?

Tags: java, iostream

I'm a beginner programmer and i have a question about iostreams.
Recently i learned how to write a string or a variable to a textfile with PrintWriter. Now i'm creating a small program but i need to output multiple variables. Do i need to create a different file for every variable or can i just output all my variables to one textfile? If so, how do i read them back into my program.

```
//write
static File data = new File ("data.txt");
static PrintWriter outputStream = new PrintWriter(data);
outputStream .println("test");
outputStream .close();

//read
Scanner inputStream = new Scanner(data);
String test = input.nextLine();
```

Comment: Just write all your variables in a for loop then use `.close()`.

Comment: Yes but how do you read it and put every line in the right variable

Comment: What are your variables? You must add them in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not 100% sure what you're trying to do exactly without seeing the variables and what you're trying to do with them. If you just want to be able to write and read multiple strings into a file, you can output everything into one single file like this if done manually:

```
    outputStream.println("test1");
    outputStream.println("test2");
    outputStream.println("test3");
    outputStream.close();
```

For reading line by line, simply do

```
    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        System.out.println(scanner.nextLine());
    }
```

Since you mentioned you're storing them as variables, then depending on the scenario you could use some type of Collections class, e.g. an ArrayList or HashMap.

```
    // add all strings from each new line to an ArrayList 
    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        varArray.add(scanner.nextLine());
    }
    // close your streams
    scanner.close();

    // iterate the ArrayList and print all values
    for (String var : varArray) {
        System.out.println(var);
    }

    // grab value by its index in the ArrayList
    System.out.println("Get variable from index 2: " + varArray.get(2));
```

In any case, unless you can rely on the order the strings are written into the file, you will need to have some condition to return the one you want. This will just print them all in the order they were inserted.